# Not getting any output

Tags: c

The content of my main.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "max_subarray_data.h"

int main()
{
    init_change();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n",i,change[i]);
    }
}
```

The content of max_subarray_data.h

```
extern int price[];
extern int change[];
extern int n;

void init_change();
```

The content of my max_subarray_data.c

```
int price[]={100,113,110,85,105,102,86,63,81,101,94,106,101,79,94,90,97};
int n=(int)(sizeof(price)/sizeof(int))-1;
int change[(int)(sizeof(price)/sizeof(int))-1];

void init_change()
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        change[i]=price[i+1]-price[i];
    }
}
```

Why am i getting no output ?

Comment: Could be an output buffering issue.  Try changing `"%d %d"` to `"%d %d\n"`.

Comment: [I do get some output](http://ideone.com/1DBh85). How are you compiling this code?

Comment: Are you linking in `max_subarray_data.o` (compilation of `max_subarray_data.c`)?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes you are right. But why am i not getting the output when I am using separate files ?

Comment: @FibonacciCoder I get output using separate files: http://pastie.org/10636553

Comment: Use `ssize_t` instead of casting like this `int n=(int)(sizeof(price)/sizeof(int))-1;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not the missing `'\n'` in `printf()` it may be because your array `change` is one element too small: as array size you use the same expression as for setting `n`, so `n-1` is the largest possible index. But then you loop from 1 to n and assign something to `change[n]`. That invokes Undefined Behaviour, so anything might happen.

Comment: I think you must point out that in [tag:c] and most languages array indexes go from `0` to `N - 1`

Comment: @iharob, I think OP knews. the loop starts at 1 because he uses `price[i-1]`

Comment: If you have modified the `for` loop in `main()` accordingly, I think that should work